# In a target shell script, how to know file it is linked from which symbolic-link?

Tags: shell

Environment: Android and shell.
The files are as below:

```
link1 ->target.sh
link2 ->target.sh
link3 ->target.sh
```

Now in the target shell script, how to know which symbolic-link file is linking to it currently?
When the target scrip is invoked from different link file, it need to call different function.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first positional parameter `$0` contains the file that was executed.

Example target.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $0
```

And then

```
$ ./target.sh
./target.sh
$ link1
link1
```

Beware that `$0` contains the full path. If you just want the executable name you can remove the path with `basename`:

```
#!/bin/sh

EXECUTABLE=$(basename "$0")

case "${EXECUTABLE}" in
    link1)
        echo "Called as link1"
        # function1
        ;;
    link2)
        echo "Called as link2"
        # function2
        ;;
    link3)
        echo "Called as link3"
        # function3 
        ;;
    target.sh)
        echo "Called as target.sh"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Some error message"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: @PerlmanSong You can then accept the answer if it solves your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers